# What Star Trek TNG Episode featured multiple versions of Data from different dimensions?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I don't remember what the episode was about, but I remember this scene where there were at least 10 different Datas and one of them had to put something back into an energy beam in order to restore the correct time-continuum.  One of the Datas realized that he was the right one, and order was restored..

Thanks

Comment: A Fistful of Datas springs to mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The episode is "[We'll Always Have Paris](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/We%27ll_Always_Have_Paris_%28episode%29)"; Season 1 episode 24, directed by Robert Becker (who also directed "The Outrageous Okona").

There were, in fact only three Cmdr Datas, one each from the past, present and future. The middle one turns out to be the one from the current timeframe.

Interestingly, this episode has a major blooper in that Data (who famously cannot use contractions) identifies himself by saying "Me. **It's** me!"

Comment: actually, if I had a nickle for every time Data used a contraction... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yY1KdQNodN0

Comment: “It’s a-me!” Considering the fact that he’s a walking computer, Data doesn’t make nearly enough Super Mario references for my liking.